# Threshold probability subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,...,n\}$ and random subset $A \in S$ and $\forall a \in A$ we choose $a$ from $S$ with probability $p$. How find threshold probability for the property of $A$ to include 4 numbers $(a,b,c,d)$ that are the solution of the equation: $a+b=c+d$ ?

Comment: At first I need to find number of different numbers that are solutions of the equation $a+b=c+d$, but I can't